# How to properly close connection pools on express finish request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, knex.js

My Express App creates many knex connections to databases dynamically, since there are many projects and different databases. Recently Im facing following error:

`TimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx)`

I want to close the connections created for each request. For that, Im using Express hook `res.on('finish', callback())`. Its fired every time the request is finished. Then I pass the funcion to remove all the created connections on `req`:

```
  closePoolOnFinish: (req, res, next) => {
    res.on('finish', () => {
      if (req.globalPool) req.globalPool.destroy()
      if (req.projectPool) req.projectPool.destroy()
    })
    next()
  }
```

However, the first request ends successfully and pools seems closed correctly but following are failing on trying to connect to database and throws following error:

```
Unable to acquire a connection
```

Note: Is this even a proper solution? Or should I increment the max available connections?

Comment: The most likely scenario is that you are not completing your explicitly created transactions, or have implicitly created but very long running transactions (i.e. a bug in your code).  Those will eat up your connection pool. If you are connecting to multiple DBs, then there will be a separate connection pool for each DB, so you might also check whether the problem is for a specific DB. Lastly, yes, it could be that you have so much activity that you need to increase the size of your connection pool(s).

Comment: @GaryL Indeed Im using transactions. Finally ended up incrementing the max pools. I wonder if theres any way to print the current number of pools in Knex. Thanks!